# How is the acetone method different from QB buffer for extraction of plant protein?

Tags: botany, proteins, lab-techniques, sds-page

I primarily work on animal tissue but I thought of running an SDS-PAGE for plant tissue just for fun. I searched for some protein extraction protocols online and I don't know which one to choose. One is the [acetone trichloroacetic acid](http://www.bidmcmassspec.org/uploads/Acetone_precipitation.pdf) method where you use the precipitate (?) and chlorophyll stays in the supertanant while the other is a QB (full form?) [extraction buffer](https://www.researchgate.net/file.PostFileLoader.html?id=54db62b5d11b8b746c8b46cb&assetKey=AS%3A273699796652033%401442266524063) which is similar to what we use in animal tissue (with a bit of DTT and PVP). Here, we use the supertanant after centrifugal ion and the chlorophyll stays in the loading sample(?). At least, this is what I gather. What are the functional differences and when to use which technique?

Since I'm planning to run a gel, which one would be the better technique?

Please correct me if wrong I'm new to this field

Protocols attached.

Comment: I can't find the mention of QB buffer in any of the linked protocols. BTW, acetone is used to remove lipids.

Comment: The extraction buffer itself is called the QB buffer I guess @WYSIWYG